# why does ruby each method throw me into implicit_render.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
cat = Hash.new
users = where("last_seen is not null")   
users.each do |u|
  profession = GeneralInformation.where("information_id = ? and information_type = 'User'", u.id).select(:profession)
  if cat.key?(profession) then cat[profession] = cat[profession] + 1 else cat[profession] = 1 end
```

i debugged this code and when the parser tries to move to the line after

```
users.each do |u|
```

i'm just redirected to implicit_render.rb file
i executed all these lines of code step by step in the rails console and it works properly there.whats the problem. why is .each method behaving weird?

Comment: is this code in a controller or in a model? It seems that this is a controller stuff to guarantee you are calling render only once. [implicity render code](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb)

Comment: in the model..which is why i'm using where method directly

Comment: This isn't an answer to your problem, but that whole last line should be `cat[profession] = (cat[profession] || 0) + 1`

Comment: @fotanus FYI the request is an ajax request and i'm rendering the cat hash using render json: cat